# Why do I have multple instances of Java running after installing HDnsight?

Tags: hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight, azul-zulu

I've installed HDInsight on a desktop computer to learn to work with Hive. When I restarted my computer and logged into my profile everything was moving slow.  I've figured out that Hadoop is running multiple instances of Java.exe. Is there a way to limit the amount of memory that Hadoop uses for this?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why Hadoop is running multiple instances of Java is because Hadoop has various daemons like namenode, secondarynamenode, datanode, jobtracker, tasktracker performing various tasks and each of the daemon is a Java process.

I am not sure about HDInsight but in Apache Hadoop you could configure the Daemon JVM Heap Sizes using by setting `HADOOP_HEAPSIZE` variable in `hadoop-env.sh` configuration file genrally located in `${HADOOP_INSTALL}/conf`. You could also tune specific hadoop daemon's for more information see this [link](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/cluster_setup.html).